# Add w3school autocomplete functionality to django form field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, autocomplete, django-forms

i want to add the [w3school.com autocomplete functionality](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) to one of my django form fields. At first I used a simple html form and it worked, but after implementing the [django-way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) of working with forms and models, I can't get the autocomplete to work anymore.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

> forms.py

```
class PlantForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Plant
    fields = ('plantname')
    widgets = {
        'plantname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Trage hier den Namen des gelieferten Produkts ein.',
                                            'class': 'autocomplete',
                                            'autocomplete': 'off'}),
```

> models.py

```
class Plant(models.Model):
     plantname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

> main.js

```
const plants = ["Strauß", "Pepperoni", "Physalis", "Aster"];

window.onload = function () {
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("id_plantname"), plants);
};
```

> index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static 'xyz/index.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'xyz/main.js' %}"></script>

<form autocomplete="off" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Eintragen</button>
</form>
```

The css and js code is copy and paste from the [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp).
I guess it has something to do with the autocomplete class. Maybe it is assigned wrong in the forms.py? The id of the field in main.js should be right according to the django documentation and my tests. Hope you can help me, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to use a library to achieve an auto-complete feature than use some code from w3school.

Use [jQuery](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and achieve the same feature efficiently with much fewer code

Firstly, create a `some_file.json` and keep the data that you want to use to autocomplete.
E.g.

```
{
    "something" : null
}
```

Import jQuery and add the following code to your x.js file.
Change it to fit your needs.

```
    $.getJSON('/static/some_dir/x.json', function(data_) {
        $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
            data: data_,
            limit: 20,
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

In x.html file, define your input tag like below

```
<input title="something" type="text" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
```

Once implemented, this should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Is this solved? If so please accept the answer to show that it's been solved.

Comment: Hi Azy_Crw4282, thanks a lot for your answer! I implemented it successfully without using a separate .json file. But it just worked directly in the xx.html. I don't know why it isn't working, when writing the exactly same code in the x.js file. The import works.